# Please help me understand this sentence: あなたに、私の両親に会ってもらいたいんですが。

Tags: giving-and-receiving

some things are not clear to me in the following sentence

```
あなたに、私の両親に会ってもらいたいんですが。
```

It's translate to "I would like you to meet my parents", but as far as i know the word `あなた` mean you. So its not suppose to be "You want to meet my parents?"

Also, I don't understand the purpose of the word `もらい`. From what I found out:

```
もらい　－ to get somebody to do something (follows a verb in "te" form)
```

but it's to vague, I don't have any idea what does it even mean.

Thanks a lot, Or

Answer (score 3, accepted):

もらう means "receive" and it is a verb whose subject must be the first person (or someone the speaker empathizes with).

Example:
私は貴方に本をもらう。Watashi wa anata ni hon o morau.
I receive a book from you.

The giver is indicated with に. In the example above it is 貴方に (from you).

もらう is used not only to "receive" objects, but also to "receive" actions.

私は貴方に読んでもらう。Watashi wa anata ni yonde morau.
Literally: I receive from you the action of reading.
In natural English: You read for me.

Every time someone does something for you, you can use the structure Verb+て+もらう.
The giver must be marked with に。

So a literal translation is:
私は あなたに、私の両親に会ってもらいたい
I want to receive from you the action of meeting my parents.

Answer (score 4):

もらう　is to get something. it can be a thing or an action. if it is an action, the verb describing the action is in て-form, so in this case 私の両親に会って　= to meet my parents.

the person you get something from is marked with に so in this case あなた = you.

もらう is in たい-from, which means I want to. んですが is typical ending for a wish, where you want it to sound more soft. like when you make a wish and want to know how the other person thinks about it, but don't want to ask too directly.

so: I would like you to meet my parents... (would you be okay with that?)

"would you be okay with that?" is not written there, only implied by the ending.

Comment: Thank you, the  んですが example taught me a new thing that I didn't even think about.